# insert into linked table with nested join fails in vba, works ok in access

Tags: mysql, vba, syntax, inner-join

My query fails with error 3127 as shown below.  Yet I clearly see the referenced column on the joined table.  Query works just fine as an access query when I paste the string from debug output window.

```
qry = "INSERT INTO modules_installed_nodes " _
        & "SELECT pm.slot_installed, n.node_id, mt.id " _
        & "FROM (parsed_modules pm " _
            & "INNER JOIN nodes n on pm.hostname LIKE n.hostname) " _
            & "INNER JOIN module_types mt on pm.model LIKE mt.name;"
```

> debug.output:INSERT INTO modules_installed_nodes SELECT pm.slot_installed, n.node_id, mt.id FROM (parsed_modules pm INNER JOIN
>   nodes n on pm.hostname LIKE n.hostname) INNER JOIN module_types mt on
>   pm.model LIKE mt.name;
>
> ErrorNo 3127 The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field 
>   name: 'node_id'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the
>   operation again.

I used a previous query without error a few lines above:

```
qry2 = "INSERT INTO virtual_switches_configured " _ 
         & "SELECT n.node_id, pvs.name, pvs.logical_id " _
         & "FROM parsed_vs pvs  " _
             & "INNER JOIN nodes n on pvs.hostname LIKE n.hostname;"
```

nodes table

```
-node_id number
-hostname short text
-model number
...
```

module_types table

```
-id number
-name shortext
...
```

modules_installed_nodes table

```
-slot_installed shorttext
-node_installed number
-model_id number
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Doesn't seem like a syntax issue because the query works in access but not sure what else it could be.  This is an ODBC linked table (mysql).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like specifying the column names was required prior to the select statement.  I didn't expect this since I am passing a value for each column.

```
qry = "INSERT INTO modules_installed_nodes " _
& "([slot_installed],[node_installed],[node_id]) " _
& "SELECT parsed_modules.[slot_installed], nodes.[node_id],module_types.[id] " _
& "FROM parsed_modules,module_types,nodes " _
& "WHERE (([nodes].[hostname] LIKE [parsed_modules].[hostname]) AND " _
     & " ([module_types].[name] LIKE [parsed_modules].[model]));"
```